# Why do I have to uninstall dll's from GAC to get my solution to build?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have a solution with perhaps 10 SharePoint projects and a number of supporting Dlls. To get my project to build I generally need to go to the GAC and uninstall all of the libraries associate with our project from the GAC.

If I don't do that I get errors stating it cant resolve the references, either to these projects or to projects dependent on those projects.

What's going on?

Why do some of my team not have this issue. we both do the same Get from source control.

Comment: Which errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you running your Visual Studio as administrator? You must run as administrator or some retracts cannot be performed

Comment: Yes I am running as Administrator.

Comment: Here is an example of an error: Error 16 The type or namespace name 'IRepository' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Dev\src\OE\Brxxxxxxxxxxs.OE.Data.ActiveDirectory\IActiveDirectoryRepository.cs 3 48 OE.AdminWebParts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on, but I know what is causing it. I have VS2013 RC installed on my machine. If I run VS 2012 installer again and run the repair, it will fix these issues.
I tried running the VS 2013 RC installer again (repair mode) and it broke it again. So I reran the VS2012 installer in repair and that fixed my problem again. So VS 2013 consistently is breaking this solution for me.
This will fix this solution for 2012 but it no longer works in VS 2013.

When I had the VS 2012 Preview installed I did see these issues briefly but they actually went away, I could not tell what it was that fixed it. With the preview, although it was a little inconsistent I could use both VS versions, on my solution. With the RC it looks like I can only get the VS 2012 to work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally GAC dlls have higher priority than the local assemblies. So if your dlls are deployed in GAC then your application would reference the ones located there (over the ones that are packaged locally to your bin directories).

So one guess would be that the GAC dlls are outdated (missing classes, methods, properties that you have just added in your code), that's why your project cannot be built.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I am really looking for an answer specific to SharePoint. Visual studio has a built in mechanism to deploy SharePoint projects to the local dev SharePoint. When it does this it will install your libraries in the GAC, assuming you have set them up to be installed into the GAC. What I want to know is why is this not working consistently. Why are project references not being found? Its not like it is using the DLL's in the GAC to reference, its saying it cannot find them, even though they are there.